# Manually Set the Date and Time on a Chromebook (ChromeOS 111)

Tags: date-time, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a 13" Lenovo Flex 5 (2022) Chromebook, running ChromeOS 111 and I need to be able to manually set the date and time.  From internet searches, I found that I should be able to use the set_time command in the Chrome Shell (CROSH) to do this, but it fails with an error (see example in code block)

```
crosh> set_time 22 April 2023 11:45am
ERROR - Time not set. Network time cannot be overridden.
ERROR - ERROR: command failed
```

From `Settings > Advanced > Date and Time` I have tried manually setting the time zone, but this isn't adequate for my need and doesn't resolve the set_time error.  I have also tried disabling all networks and running the command, with the same result.

I'm pretty new to Chrome OS, so I've thought of a couple other ideas, but not sure if these would work or how to execute them (change the NTP target or change the hosts file to loopback so the network time fails -or- create a local NTP server to manually set the time).

How can I manually set the time on ChromeOS?